# Stm32f103 chip TIM3 and TIM8 of the ordinary PWM output conflict?

Tags: pwm

I am designing a device that outputs 25 **PWM** at the same time. The chip model is **stm32f103rf**. However, when I find the information, see the Internet was said **TIM3** and **TIM8** **PWM output** conflict, can only choose one of them. I went to the **ST company** to find this chip information did not see this problem, so I would like to know, **in practical applications, TIM3 and TIM8 PWM output will not be a conflict**. Thank you!